# How can I add a hyperlink in my bibliography using apa style?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, apa-style

I am trying to make a bibliography with the APA style in which a reference in the bibliography links to the website where the article is located. However using the APA style I cannot get this sorted while apalike gives me an error.

### MWE:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{book}
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \begin{document}

 Text goes here \cite{1}.

 \bibliographystyle{apa}
 \bibliography{Thesis_Bibliography}
 \end{document}
```

I load my citations from EndNote which does export the url and the doi, however I cannot call them using the APA style.

.bib file inputs:

```
@article{1,
author = {Esen, Mehmet and Durmuş, Aydin and Durmuş, Ayla},
title = {Geometric design of solar-aided latent heat store depending on      various parameters and phase change materials},
journal = {Solar Energy},
volume = {62},
number = {1},
pages = {19-28},
ISSN = {0038-092X},
DOI = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0038-092X(97)00104-7},
url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038092X97001047},
year = {1998},
type = {Journal Article}
}
```

This gives the following output, the lay-out is exactly how I want it but the text is not clickable. How can I make the text link to the URL?

[image: ref]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you sure the APA style shall show it for an article?

Comment: APA style is not supposed to provide the URL in the bibliography as output. That is why I want to make a reference link to the URL to include it anyways.